# Python/Scrapy handle missing table data, list index out of range

Tags: python, pandas, loops, csv, scrapy

I'm using round-col as the list length as there's always data in that column which tells me the size of the table.
I'm scraping data to csv so all fields have to correspond but the trouble I'm facing is when the loop hits 'no data' the list index goes out of range or 'TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not sub scriptable

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from bigcrawler.items import BigcrawlerItem

class CrawlbotSpider(Spider):
   name = 'bigcrawler'
   allowed_domains = ['www.matchstat.com']
   start_urls = ['https://matchstat.com/tennis/all-upcoming-matches']

    custom_settings = {
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv' ,
    'FEED_URI': 'test.csv'
    }
def parse(self ,response):

    hxs = Selector(response)
    item = BigcrawlerItem()

    round_col = hxs.xpath(".//tr[contains(@class, 'match')]/td[contains(@class, 'round')]/text()").extract()
    event_col = hxs.xpath(".//tr[contains(@class, 'match')]/td[contains(@class, 'event-name')]/a/text()").extract()
    player1_col = hxs.xpath(".//tr[contains(@class, 'match')]/td[contains(@class, 'player-name')][1]/a/text()").extract()
    player2_col = hxs.xpath(".//tr[contains(@class, 'match')]/td[contains(@class, 'player-name')][2]/a/text()").extract()
    odds1_col = hxs.xpath(".//tr[contains(@class, 'match highlight')]/td[contains(@class, 'odds-td odds-0')]/a[contains(@class, 'btn btn-default virtual btn-xs btn-outcome odds')][1]/text()").extract_first()
    odds2_col = hxs.xpath( ".//tr[contains(@class, 'match highlight')]/td[contains(@class, 'odds-td odds-1')]/a[contains(@class, 'btn btn-default virtual btn-xs btn-outcome odds')][2]/text()").extract_first()
    h2h_col = hxs.xpath(".//tr[contains(@class, 'match')]/td[contains(@class, 'h2h')]/a[contains(@class, 'h2h')]/text()").extract_first()


    for x in range(0,len(round_col)):
        item['round'] = round_col[x].strip()
        item['event1'] = event_col[x].strip()
        item['player_1'] = player1_col[x].strip()
        item['player_2'] = player2_col[x].strip()
        item['player_1_odds'] = odds1_col[x].strip()
        item['player_2_odds'] = odds2_col[x].strip()
        item['h_2_h'] = h2h_col[x].strip()
        yield item
```

If the list changes shape the data is useless, How do I modify the loop to insert "None" when it hits no element keeping the len loop alive?

Or is there another approach I could take?
Thanks.

Comment: One option is write this as `x < len(odds_1_col) and odds1_col[x].strip() or None` but I think this should be rewritten... probably as a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to build based on the columns, you need to loop over the rows, and start building the items per row, I've used item loaders here so that you can avoid several `.extract_first()` or `.strip()`, please try this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

# This should go to items.py
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import TakeFirst, MapCompose
from operator import methodcaller


class MatchStatItem(scrapy.Item):
    round = scrapy.Field()
    event1 = scrapy.Field()
    player_1 = scrapy.Field()
    player_2 = scrapy.Field()
    player_1_odds = scrapy.Field()
    player_2_odds = scrapy.Field()
    h_2_h = scrapy.Field()


class MatchStatItemLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_item_class = MatchStatItem
    default_input_processor = MapCompose(methodcaller('strip'))
    default_output_processor = TakeFirst()

class MatchStatSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "matchstat"
    allowed_domains = ["matchstat.com"]
    start_urls = ['https://matchstat.com/tennis/all-upcoming-matches']

    def parse(self, response):  
        for row in response.css('tr.match'):
           il = MatchStatItemLoader(selector=row)
           il.add_css('round', '.round::text')
           il.add_css('event1', '.event-name a::text')
           il.add_css('player_1', '.player-name:nth-child(3) a::text')
           il.add_css('player_2', '.player-name:nth-child(4) a::text')
           il.add_css('player_1_odds', '.odds-td.odds-0 [payout]::text')
           il.add_css('player_2_odds', '.odds-td.odds-1 [payout]::text')
           il.add_css('h_2_h', 'a.h2h::text')
           yield il.load_item()
```

The output should be something like:

```
{'event1': u'ATP World Tour Finals', 'h_2_h': u'H2H 3-0', 'player_1': u'Roger Federer', 'player_1_odds': u'1.10', 'player_2': u'Jack Sock', 'player_2_odds': u'7.00', 'round': u'RR A'}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but when I run this code I get an error 'does not support field: Selector' I'm using the import statement in spider.py from scrapy.selector import Selector and still getting an error

Comment: weird, which version of scrapy are you using? (perhaps could you show a bit more of the error message).

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, I got your script to work. My issue was with csv item exporters, I think scrapy got confused with over-riding the basic settings.

Comment: great, if it helped you please feel free to mark this question as answered :)

Comment: I will thanks again, If I add a second url to start_urls. what would it take to append the data to the output csv?

Comment: if you run it like `scrapy crawl matchstat -o out.csv` all the items extracted will be appended to the output csv file :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use CSS selector like this way

```
for match in response.css("table.draw-table.filter-table tr.match):
    item['round'] = "".join(a.strip() for a in match.css("td.round *::text").extract())
    #do the other TDs just like above
    yield item
```

This way you will not incur any error, if data does not exists for a particular TD, it will show as empty in your output CSV

Answer (score 0):

better if you extract data in this way(replace your parse method body with this code, and also modify it as required):

```
data = []
rows = response.xpath('//tr[contains(@class, "match ")]')
for i in rows:
    round_col = i.css("td.round::text").extract_first()
    event_col = i.css("td.event-name::text").extract_first()
    players = i.css("td.player-name")
    player1_col = players[0].css("a::text").extract_first()
    player2_col = players[0].css("a::text").extract_first()
    odds1_col = i.css("td.odds-td odds-0 a.btn.btn-default.virtual.btn-xs.btn-outcome.odds::text").extract_first()
    odds2_col = i.css("td.odds-td odds-1 a.btn.btn-default.virtual.btn-xs.btn-outcome.odds::text").extract_first()
    h2h_col = i.css("td.h2h a.h2h::text").extract_first()    
    data.append({'round': round_col, 'event': event_col, 'player1': player1_col, 'player2': player2_col, 'odds1':odds1_col, 'odds2':odds2_col, 'h2h':h2h_col})

print data
```